# How can I update a reactive variable before submitting a form?

Tags: vuejs3, naiveui

I have a form with a username and password input, and I want to submit the form and log the user in when both inputs have a value. I'm using Vue.js, and I have a reactive variable called **`me`** that represents the user who is currently logged in.

Here's my code:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { NButton, NCard, NForm, NFormItem, NInput, NSpace, useDialog } from 'naive-ui';
import { useLogin } from '@/composables/API/useLogin';
import { computed, ref, watchEffect } from 'vue';
import { useRouter, useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { useMe } from '@/composables/API/useMe';
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';

const { mutate: login } = useLogin();
const credentials = ref({ username: '', password: '' });
const { data: me } = useMe();
const { t } = useI18n({ useScope: 'global' });
const dialog = useDialog();
const router = useRouter();
const route = useRoute();
const redirectRoute = computed(() => {
  const redirect = route.query.returnUrl;
  if (redirect) {
    return redirect as string;
  }
  return '/';
});
const handleSubmit = () => {
  if (credentials.value.username !== '' && credentials.value.password !== '') {
    watchEffect(() => {
      if (me.value === null) {
        dialog.error({
          title: t('login.errorPopup.title'),
          content: t('login.errorPopup.content'),
          positiveText: t('login.errorPopup.positiveText'),
        });
      } else {
        login(credentials.value, {
          onSuccess: () => {
            router.replace(redirectRoute.value);
          },
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <n-space vertical justify="center" align="center" :size="20" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh">
    <img alt="GPI logo" src="@/assets/logo.svg" style="width: 200px" />
    <n-card :title="$t('login.title')" size="huge" embedded style="width: 400px">
      <!-- <template #cover><img alt="GPI logo" src="@/assets/logo.svg" /></template> -->
      <n-form
        :model="credentials"
        @submit.prevent="handleSubmit"
        label-placement="left"
        label-width="auto"
        label-align="left"
      >
        <n-form-item :label="$t('login.username')" path="username">
          <n-input v-model:value="credentials.username" :placeholder="$t('login.username')" />
        </n-form-item>
        <n-form-item :label="$t('login.password')" path="password">
          <n-input
            v-model:value="credentials.password"
            type="password"
            show-password-on="mousedown"
            :placeholder="$t('login.password')"
          />
        </n-form-item>
        <n-form-item>
          <n-button attr-type="submit" type="primary" block>{{ $t('login.submit') }}</n-button>
        </n-form-item>
      </n-form>
    </n-card>
  </n-space>
</template>
```

The problem is that the **`me`** variable is not updated before the form is submitted. As a result, the **`dialog.error`** always runs, even when the user is logged in.

How can I make sure that the **`me`** variable is updated before the form is submitted? I've tried using **`watch`** instead of **`watchEffect`**, but it didn't seem to help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you are using `watchEffect()` as a regular method, which does not work:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  if (credentials.value.username !== '' && credentials.value.password !== '') {
    watchEffect(() => { // <------ this does not make sense
      ...
    });
  }
};
```

Calling `watchEffect()` registers a handler that is executed every time a dependency changes. It is not meant to be run conditionally and particularly not multiple times. Similar as you wouldn't run `document.addEventListener()` multiple times for the same event and handler.

But the idea of composables is that you don't have to setup watchers in the component at all - this is the logic you extract into the composable, and you import a ref that is always up to date. You didn't post the code of `useMe()`, but you would set up a watcher there (If you have problems with that, you should probably edit your question or ask a new one).

In the component, what you want to do is just check the value:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  if (!credentials.value.username || !credentials.value.password) {
    return
  }
  if (me.value === null) { // <-----  "me" should always be up to date
    showDialog()
  } else {
    doLogin()
  }
};
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: i'll let you now later